# Ограничения даты в DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, дата, calendar, datepicker

Есть два DatePickerDialog. Выбранная дата в первом должна стать минимальной датой во втором. 
Сделал это так

```
 private void setInitialDateTime(TextView textView) {

    textView.setText(DateUtils.formatDateTime(getActivity(),
            dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis(),
            DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR
    ));

}
// установка обработчика выбора даты
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener fD=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        setInitialDateTime(finishDate);
    }
};
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener bD=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        dateAndTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        finishPicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis());

        setInitialDateTime(beginDate);
    }
};


// отображаем диалоговое окно для выбора даты
public void setDate(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dialog) {

    beginPicker.getDatePicker().updateDate(dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    beginPicker.show();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_period, container, false);
    beginDate= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.beginDate );
    finishDate= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.finishDate);
    beginDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           setDate(bD);
        }
    });
    finishDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finishPicker.show();
        }
    });

    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpagerDetalization);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsDetalization);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    beginPicker=new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),bD,dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    finishPicker=new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),fD,dateAndTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), dateAndTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), dateAndTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    beginPicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(dateAndTime.getTimeInMillis());

    setInitialDateTime(beginDate);
    setInitialDateTime(finishDate);
    return view;
}
```

Но теперь возникла проблема. Если я заново выбираю на первом DatePickerDialog новую дату, то во втором минимум не меняется

первый DatePicker

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

второй DatePicker

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

снова первый DatePicker

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Снова второй DatePicker

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В обработчике onDataSet() запоминай выбранную дату и там же выставляй setMinDate() второму пикеру